# Stop Magento reserving stock

Tags: stock, inventory, management

Is it possible to stop Magento reserving stock when an order comes in?

When an order comes in Magento reserves the stock but so does our 3rd party backend inventory system, so the stock ends up becoming reserved twice. This means we have less stock available in Magento than we do actually have available.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, built in to the inventory of Magento.

> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory

In here, look for the option **Decrease Stock When Order is Placed** Set this to be No.

This is a global configuration option however, so if you have multiple websites this will do it for all websites.

There have been other suggestions posed in other threads which you could use if you cant use the above option.

Those involve overwriting the after sale observers such that you re-stock the items in the order and then your processing would continue as normal.